# What is the `domain` attribute in Rails.application.configure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the `domain` attribute in the `Rails.application.configure do` block?

Currently I have,

```
Rails.application.configure do
   config.domain = 'www.my-site.com'
end
```

I couldn't find an explanation from Google, and it seems like everything works the same if I remove it.

Does it have a specific purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard Rails config, it was probably set by another dev. Check for occurrences on `config.domain` usage on the code and you will probably understand what it does.

I'd guess it is used at least in `config/environments/production.rb` as the default host for e-mail.